# gmail add on multipart/form-data app script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, gmail-addons

i'm building a gmail add on application to read a current email and retrieve the gmail attachment associated with the email. 
Once I get the blob of the attachment I try to upload it to my API via a **multipart/form-data** post request. Currently, my request is failing with a 500  while my postman request work just fine.

my back end is giving the following exception: 
**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Either BinaryRead, Form, Files, or InputStream was accessed before the internal storage was filled by the caller of HttpRequest.GetBufferedInputStream.**

with postman I don't get any error.

Not sure if i'm creating the request in app script currently.  Here is my code.

```
    var blob = 
     Utilities.newBlob(parsedBlob,payload.contentType,payload.name);
    Logger.log('encode url ' + encodedUrl)
    var metadata = {
        'account_ref.id': payload.metaData.account_ref.id,
        'matter_ref.id': payload.metaData.matter_ref.id,
         description: "uploaded from gmail add on.",
         content_type: payload.contentType,
         file_name: 'test.png',
         size: JSON.parse(payload.size).toString(),
    };

    for (var i in metadata) {
        data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + i + "\" 
         \r\n\r\n" + metadata[i] + "\r\n";
    }
    data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\"; filename=\"" + 
    blob.getName() + "\"\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type:" + blob.getContentType() + "\r\n\r\n";
    var payload = Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes()
                                         .concat(blob.getBytes())
                                         .concat(Utilities.newBlob("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n").getBytes());

    var headers = {
        Authorization: Utilities.formatString("Bearer %s", this.oauthService.getAccessToken())
    };

    var options = {
        method: "post",
      contentLength: blob.getBytes().length,
        payload: payload,
        contentType : "multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8; boundary=--" + 
        boundary,
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers: headers,
    };
```

Anything i'm doing wrong in preparing the payload?

Comment: To help you create requests to Gmail API, you can refer to the [apps script documentation focusing on the Gmail Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/). Also, for an in-depth guide to access Gmail API, visit the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/).

Comment: @VladimirCastillo, how do you get boundary?